# what is the definition of "flexibility" of a method in Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning

I want to find the definition of "flexibility" of a method in machine learning, just like Lasso, SVM, Least Squares.
here is a representation of the tradeoff between flexibility and interpretability.

And I also think flexibility is a detailed numerical thing.
Because of my reputation, I cannot upload the pictures. If you want to know some details, you can read *An Introduction to Statistical Learning*, the pictures are on page 25 and page 31.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of "Flexibility" of a model as the model's "curvy-ness" when graphing the model equation.  A linear regression is said to be be inflexible.  On the other hand, if you have 9 training sets that are each very different, and you require a more rigid decision boundary, the model will be deemed flexible, just because the model can't be a straight line.

Of course, there's an essential assumption that these models are adequate representations of the training data (a linear representation doesn't work well for highly spread out data, and a jagged multinomial representation doesn't work well with straight lines).

As a result, A flexible model will:

1. Generalize well across the different training sets

   - Comes at a cost of higher variance.  That's why flexible models are generally associated with low bias
2. Perform better as complexity increases and/or # of data points increase (up to a point, where it won't perform better)

Answer (score 0):

There's no rigor definition of method's flexibility. The aforementioned book says

> We can try to address this problem by choosing *flexible* models that can fit many different possible functional forms flexible for f.

In that sense Least Squares is less flexible since it's a linear model. Kernel SVM, on contrary, doesn't have such limitation and can model fancy non-linear functions.

Flexibility isn't measured in numbers, the picture in the book shows relational data only, not actual points on a 2D-plane.

Comment: thanks for your answer, however the figure at the page 31 in the book show that the flexibility can be measured, we can see the axis values of the right of this figure.

Comment: Well, I'd say that it's flexibility of a particular model. It looks like they fit polynomials to data there. Then one can say that flexibility equals degree of a polynomial, since the higher degree of a polynomial - the more points you can "connect", so model becomes more flexible. But that's not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

Flexibility describes the ability to increase the degrees of freedom available to the model to "fit" to the training data.